# Android Adapter not inflating view correctly

Tags: android

My layout XML file and the layout displayed on my phone after inflating the file are radically different. For some reason, when inflating the view in a `ListView`, many of the elements become vertically centered; to be precise, they layer on top of each other. I have confirmed that this is due to the `Adapter` code and not the layout itself; if I create a new `Activity` and use `setContentView`, the view appears as it should (as it appears in the XML preview).
Sorry if my wording is poor, I have a pretty high fever and can't think straight (maybe that's why I can't solve this issue).

Screenshots (some photoshopping to save company privacy):

XML Preview:

[image]

What it actually looks like:

[image]

Adapter Code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Item item;
    private Activity context;

    public CustomAdapter(Item item, Activity context)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return item;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

XML Source:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/middleThing"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topRightIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:maxHeight="25dp"
            android:maxWidth="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_e" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottomRightIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:maxHeight="25dp"
            android:maxWidth="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_e" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/middleThing"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/middleThing"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftCol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/leftTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/middleThing"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/primaryText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/primaryDisk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/primaryText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:maxWidth="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/store" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/snapshotDisk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:maxWidth="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/store" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snapshotText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/snapshotDisk"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/deDisk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:maxWidth="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/store" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_direct"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/deDisk"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:maxWidth="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_direct" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/deDisk"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/snapshotText"
            android:layout_below="@id/primaryDisk"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:maxHeight="25dp"
            android:maxWidth="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_s" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/dedupText"
            android:layout_below="@id/snapshotDisk"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:maxHeight="25dp"
            android:maxWidth="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_s" >

        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/rightTitle"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/middleThing"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mirrorText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/miDisk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/mirrorText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:maxWidth="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/store" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dedrDisk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:maxWidth="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/store" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dedrtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/dedrDisk"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to replace `null` with `parent` in `getView/vi.inflate`

Comment: Tried that before, unfortunately it crashes on inflate with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the 3 argument version of `inflate` giving the parent but passing `false` so it doesn't add the view:

```
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, parent, false);
```

Comment: ... Wow, that fixed it. Why does that work? Gonna go look at the source code now :P
Thanks so much!